# how to search a combination od dot and forward slash in python

Tags: python, regex

I am beginner in Python and I want to replace some specific characters from my string by regex.

```
HR_list = '../frankfurt/', '/CA/en/vancouver', '../../../IT/en/rom/'
```

If my string includes '../' I want to replace it with DE/en, and if my string includes '../../../' I wan o replace it with " ". So my code is:

```
for href in HR_list:
    if (re.findall('\\b\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\\b', href)):
        LIST.append("mystring" + (href.replace("../../..", "")))
    elif (re.findall('\\b\.\.\\b', href)):
        LIST.append("mystring" + (href.replace("..", "/DE/en")))
    else:
        LIST.append("mystring" + href)
```

The expected result should be:

```
mystring/DE/en/frankfurt, mystring/CA/en/vancouver, mystring/IT/en/rom/
```

Comment: what is the code output?

Comment: Count the occurence maybe. Like `(\.\.\/){1}` and replace with `/DE/en/`. And `(\.\.\/){3}` and replace with `/`.

Comment: This might be a X/Y question. Do you really want to flatten the path, then make sure that *that* path is inside a certain directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `replace` twice:

```
HR_list = '../frankfurt/', '/CA/en/vancouver', '../../../IT/en/rom/'

['mystring' + href.replace('../../..', '').replace('..', '/DE/en') for href in HR_list]
# ['mystring/DE/en/frankfurt/', 'mystring/CA/en/vancouver', 'mystring/IT/en/rom/']
```